# BubbleSort -my code returns random addresses

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have implemented the code for BubbleSort algorithm but it returns a weird error could you please tell me what the problem is?

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static int[] unsorted = new int[5];

    public void assignRandom(){
        for(int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++){
            unsorted[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 10;
        }
    }

    public void swapValues(int first, int second){

        int temp = unsorted[first];
        unsorted[first] = unsorted[second];
        unsorted[second] = temp;
    }

    public void bubbleSort() {

        for(int i = unsorted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(unsorted[j] > unsorted[j+1])
                    swapValues(j,j+1);
                }
            }
    System.out.print(unsorted);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BubbleSort newBubble = new BubbleSort();
        newBubble.assignRandom();
        newBubble.bubbleSort();
   }
}
```

This is basically a code that does bubblesort (assignmRandom for assigning random value to the array and then sort)

It returns: [I@1658fe12

Comment: "but it returns a weird error" What is the error? BaconNotFoundException?

Comment: I have no idea what a "weird error" is. Please clarify. Describe the error in detail, where the source of the error is, and what you have tried to do to resolve it.

Comment: @hexafraction That is an entirely reasonable error. I'd classify BaconOverflowException as "weird". A BNFE is a legitimate cause of concern.

Comment: @JasonC Skillets can only take limited stacks of meat.

Comment: For array printing use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

Comment: @hexafraction Consider using an optimized cooking algorithm and a SkilletPool to take better advantage of a multiple burner stove.

Comment: @hexafraction, @Jason C: `BaconNotFoudException` is *not* an error *nor* a cause for concern, it's a cause for **war**.

Comment: @hexafraction: Then implement an iterative fry instead of deep recursive fry, and make sure you have ample garbage collection to skim the rendered bacon fat.

Comment: @Jason Or we could just consume a non-bacon that implements Edible. Like Tofu or Pasta generated by MagicPotPastaFactory.

Comment: @hexafraction: Blasphemy.

Comment: @Jason "Blasphemy is the act of insulting or showing contempt or lack of reverence for a religious deity, irreverence towards religious or holy persons or things, or toward something considered sacred or inviolable." Bacon is neither a religious deity, sacred, nor inviolable. Many people EAT it.

Comment: @hexafraction: [Colloquial usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy#Colloquial_usage). It could NOT be anymore perfect that Sir Francis **Bacon** used *blasphemy* in this way.

Comment: @Jason and JasonC: Please take discussion to [cooking.SE].

Answer (score 4):

That's not a *random* address. That's the `toString` representation of an `int[]`:

```
[I@1658fe12
```

`[` means array, `I` means of integers, and `1658fe12` is the `hashCode` of the array. This representation is from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()):

> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

And, for [`Class.getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29):

> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more `'['` characters representing the depth of the array nesting. The encoding of element type names is as follows:
>
> Element Type: `int`, Encoding: `I`

The `hashCode` of an array is the identity `hashCode` inherited from `Object` which is approximately a representation of the memory location of the array (not *exactly*; details, always the details).

If you want to print an array, you have to say

```
for(int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(unsorted[i]);
}
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't print the elements of a Java array like that. Instead, iterate over all the elements of the array and print them individually.

```java
for (int i: unsorted) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bubble sort is fine. But the way you are printing your array is wrong. You are printing the array Object which gives you result below,

```
[I@1658fe12
```

Try printing your array as

```
    for (int a : unsorted)
        System.out.println(a);
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] unsorted = new int[5];
```

Here **unsorted is an object of type int** which holds 5 int values.

```
 System.out.print(unsorted);
```

You are basically printing the **toString** representation

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.
of the object array.

Loop through the array and print the values. `unsorted[i]. i ranges from 0 to 4`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your wrong array printing line with this statement:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(unsorted));
```

Answer (score 0):

As every other answer has said, you are printing a memory address, not the array. However, instead of using a for loop to print an array, you can just use `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(unsorted))`, as explaned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java).